# derivative of function of type $e^{\alpha t}$

Tags: derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

Stating the problem:

A capacitance is loaded through a resistor according to the formula
$$U(t) = U_{m}(1-e^{-\alpha t})\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

At time $T$ the voltage $U(T)$ reaches the critical value $U_{0}<U_{m}$ and with the help of an active element the voltage is reset to $0$ and the charging starts again. This leads to a periodic signal with period $T$. The values of $U_{m}$ and $T$ are fixed. we may choose the values of $U_{0}$ and $\alpha$.

a) The period $T$ should not be sensitive to small variations of $U_{0}$ e.g. caused by temperature variations. Verify that this condition is satisfied if the slope of the voltage $U(t)$ at time $t = T$ is maximal. The answer is that

$$U_{0} \approx \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \Delta T$$

For $\Delta T$ to be minimal for a given value of $\Delta U_{0}$ we need thus a large derivative $\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}$

b) Find the optimal value for $\alpha$ and $U_{0}$

Answer: the slope of the curve is determined by 
$$U'(t) = U_{m}\alpha e^{-\alpha t}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
Now this new expression has to be as large as possible, as function of the parameter $\alpha$.

$$\text{Thus we need the zeros of the derivative with respect to $\alpha$}\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}U'(T) = U_{m}e^{-\alpha T} (1-\alpha T)\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

This derivative vanishes for $\alpha = \frac{1}{T}$ and thus the optimal choice is

$$U_{0} = U_{m}(1-e^{-\alpha T}) = U_{m}(1-\frac{1}{e})\tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

**Here is what I don't understand:**

1. why do we need the zero of the derivative of (2) with respect $\alpha$ to find that the expression (2) be as large as possible
2. Which derivative rule is used to get from (2) to (4)?
3. I also don't understand why $\alpha = \frac{1}{T}$ is the optimal choice

Answer (score 1):

1. Optimisation: when the derivative is zero there is a stationary point, indicating maxima/minima which can be determined using second derivatives.
2. Product rule: $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ with respect to the variable you are trying to differentiate
3. Set $U_{m}e^{-\alpha T} (1-\alpha T)=0$. What are the options?

Comment: Thank you @TheSimpliFire: 1. ok, 2. How did you "spot" that you have to use the product rule and not the chain rule. 3. There are no options given in the problem

Comment: Because there are two functions: $\alpha$ and $\exp(-\alpha t)$. For 3, could $U_m$ be $0$? What about $\exp(-\alpha t)$?